# What should one do in case of whey protein allergy?

Tags: nutrition, protein, supplements, whey

I've been using a whey protein concentrate by an Indian brand named Muscleblaze. I had been reading reviews from the internet that one should shift to American protein brands as they have a better quality control during the manufacturing process and the product is much better.

I switched to Muscletech and I took their whey protein concentrate. I left that protein because it had 2.5 gms of creatine mixed with every scoop. I usually develop bloating if I take creatine, even if in small amounts. Then I read about the reviews of MyProtein on the website labdoor. I bought their protein concentrate. I really loved the protein, especially with milk. But I started encountering an upset stomach and flatulence. I tried taking it without milk too, but I had similar problems, although less.

I don't understand what's wrong. I'm unable to supplement protein through food as I'm a student eating at a mess. I don't understand why should I encounter this problem after switching to a supposedly better product. Are such things typically encountered for whey protein users? Have I developed some disease? Should I try some other brand or switch back to my previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda sounds like you might just be developing a lactose intolerance. People don't just start out lactose intolerant. People develop it as they age. After all, all babies start out drinking milk. Same thing happened to me. Drank milk and protein all the time, and suddenly started getting an upset stomach. There is lactose in whey protein, even without milk. If you get whey protein isolate however, there's almost no lactose. Try a whey protein isolate powder without milk. If you don't get an upset stomach, you probably developed a lactose intolerance.

Just a note if you do decide to try a whey protein isolate. Many companies advertise as whey protein isolate, even though they're actually a blend of isolate and concentrate. Whey protein concentrate does contain lactose. So make sure you look at the ingredients list and make sure it only lists whey protein isolate.

## EDIT

You can't develop an intolerance to isolate like you could develop lactose intolerance. I suppose you COULD develop some kind of dairy allergy, like a casein allergy, but that's not remotely the same thing as a lactose intolerance. If you develop some kind of allergy to whey or milk, than it'll present differently. You'll have an upset stomach, your lips will itch, you'll get hives, etc. Like any other allergy, symptoms will vary from person to person depending on the severity of the allergy.

I suppose you could also be suffering some sort of allergic reaction to some other ingredients in the protein you're buying. For example, maybe you're allergic to peanuts and the new protein powder you're buying contains some peanuts. It could be anything. But in my eyes, its MOST LIKELY lactose intolerance.

Comment: What if I develop intolerance to whey protein isolate also? Does that signify another ailment?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. I've  been noticing that I'm developing flatulence from milk also, which didn't exist before. I'm going to experiment with whey isolate. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Several factors can be involved in this. How much amount are you taking? Taking excess amounts may cause upset stomach and bloat. You had less problems while consuming MyProtein without milk, that means you may be consuming too much of it.

Also, it is advised that you fully ensure that the ingredients required to produce this supplement are genuine and void of any "extra ingredients" since they are the most troublesome.

Lastly, if this supplement is still causing problems even when consumed in "normal amounts" then you would be better off finding an alternative since not every supplement is produced with the same source ingredients.